# VBA adodb. Would I be overwriting the connections? Does it naturally timeout?

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I recently coded something for an assignment and I lost marks for not closing a connection and I'm curious about two things. First do ADODB connections for VBA naturally timeout after a few seconds and would I be overwriting the connection for my code included below or would I end up having multiple ADODB connections? In essence, did I do anything wrong by not closing the connections? Thanks.

```
Option Explicit
'Declaring all necessary variables - Global saves me from redeclaring and allows to be carried
Public dbMyDatabase As String, CnctSource As String, Src As String
Public rstNewQuery As ADODB.Recordset, cntStudConnection As ADODB.Connection
Public Selected1st As String
Private Sub Cancel_Click()
Unload Me
Worksheets("Question3").Range("D4:E9").Clear
End Sub
Private Sub Clear_Click()
Worksheets("Question3Products").Range("C3:H42").Clear
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Get database and links it
dbMyDatabase = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SalesOrders.mdb"
Set cntStudConnection = New ADODB.Connection
CnctSource = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & dbMyDatabase & ";"
cntStudConnection.Open ConnectionString:=CnctSource
'Commence Query for Categories
Set rstNewQuery = New ADODB.Recordset
 rstNewQuery.Open Source:="Categories", ActiveConnection:=cntStudConnection
Range("D4").CopyFromRecordset rstNewQuery
Range("D4:E9").Name = "BufferRange"
TheList.RowSource = "BufferRange"
TheList.Selected(1) = True
'Input Into Listbox
'Decided that clearing the values for connections would be redundant and wasteful.
End Sub
Private Sub FindInfo_Click()
Dim i As Integer
'Switching Sheets and Clearing Previous Variables
Worksheets("Question3Products").Activate
Range("C3:H42").Clear
'Selecting Value user wishes to search for
For i = 0 To TheList.ListCount - 1
If TheList.Selected(i) Then
    Selected1st = TheList.List(i)
End If
Next i
'Commence query to search. Decided not to make a function to call upon due to different variables and only 2 instances of use
dbMyDatabase = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SalesOrders.mdb"
Set cntStudConnection = New ADODB.Connection
CnctSource = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & dbMyDatabase & ";"
cntStudConnection.Open ConnectionString:=CnctSource
Set rstNewQuery = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim StringUse As String
StringUse = "SELECT* From Products WHERE CategoryID = " & Selected1st
rstNewQuery.Open Source:=StringUse, ActiveConnection:=cntStudConnection
Range("C3").CopyFromRecordset rstNewQuery
Range("F3:F42").Style = "Currency"
End Sub
```

Comment: It's good practice not to hold a connection for longer than you need to.  If you don't close it, it will remain open as long as it's in scope.  Did you also lose marks for not indenting ?  :-/

Comment: Nah, just new to the format of Stack Overflow. I was just wondering if I ran the FindInfo sub, would I end up having two connections or only one since I used the same variables for the connection? Would the recordset simply reinitialize?

Comment: You also did not declare (Dim) the connection and recordset variables.  The correct type for an ADO connection is ADODB.Connection and for the recordsets is ADODB.Recordset.  Variables are confined to their scope (normally the function they are declared in), but can be passed as arguments to functions/subs.  If you have an active connection in sub A which then calls sub B, and sub B establishes another connection, you can in fact have two open connections.  It would be better to pass the connection as an argument to sub B.

Comment: Actually, you did declare them as globals.  You can do that, in which case the scope of the variable is global and you would be overwriting/reopening the connection when you Set and reopen it later.  Global variables should be used sparingly and are really unnecessary here.

Comment: Yeah, I really should have declared it locally. However, there isn't anything wrong with the way my code operates correct and once I close my form, will the connection be closed?

Comment: VBA is pretty tolerant, under normal circumstances your connection would be closed and the memory freed when it leaves scope.  If this is code from a userForm, that will happen when the form us Unloaded.  If it is attached to a workbook or a module, it might not be until you close the workbook.

Comment: The problem here is that you are assuming it always gets to that point cleanly.  What happens if your code has an error and it doesn't finish running?  Or your Excel crashes?  VBA/Excel will still try to clean things up in these situations, but accidents do happen and you could end up with orphaned connections or record locks on your database.  It's much better to assume the worst - only keep connections open if you need them, add good error-trapping to close them out cleanly if something happens, etc.